# How to export a module which is imported in ES6?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vite

Here are 3 files:

```js
// ./app/index.ts
const app = {
  test: 1,
  ...
}
export default app
```

```js
// ./app.ts
import app from './app/index'

export default app
```

```js
// ./index.vue
import { test } from './app.ts'

console.log(test)
```

When I run `index.vue` an error shows:

**SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/Users/VJ/Desktop/project/app.ts?t=1691652606598' does not provide an export named 'test'**

How can I fix it?

Comment: p.s. For some reason, I have to use `./app.ts` as a transfer module.

Comment: *./app.ts*: `export const {test} = app;` - I mean, if you want to import test, you have to export test I guess

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX . But if here are a plenty of interfaces in `./app/index.ts`, I need to add them all in `./app.ts` again, it's too tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `import { test } from './app.ts'` to work `app.ts` needs to have a *named export* `test`. Yours only has a *default* export.

If you don't want to explicitly export every property of the object I suggest to use object destructuring in `index.vue`:

```
import app from './app.ts'
const {test} = app

console.log(test)
```

---

FWIW, if you have to use `app.ts` as intermediate module (for whatever reason) you can rewrite it to

```
export {default} from './app/index'
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the way that should work.

./app/index.ts:

```
const app = {
    test: 1,
    // ...
};

export { app };
```

./app.ts:

```
import { app } from './app/index';

export default app;
```

./index.vue:

```
import app from './app.ts';

console.log(app.test);
```

Comment: Thanks I got this.
I'm finding some way to make `import { test } from './app.ts'` works properly tho.

Comment: then you need to export app.test first

Comment: That means in `./app.ts`, I have to list all the interfaces already listed in `./app/index.ts`, it's really kinda tedious T.T